# Java reverse arrays help needed?

Tags: java, arrays

I am in a java bootcamp and had an assignment about reversing an array and printing it out. I figured it out after some searching and etc. But I do not get it here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment_01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr;
        arr = new int[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers for array");
            arr[i] = num.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i - 1] + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

I do not get why the  - 1 is added to the array. I tried to read other articles here but for some reason it is just getting past me. I am sorry for bothering you all but I know I need to be able to understand it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you really don't have an issue to be solved.

Comment: @theblindprophet  Thank You. Did not really know where to put it and figured it was a question so I was unsure. It's really frustrating me that it is not clicking with me  lol

Comment: You're subtracting 1 from the loop value because it ranges from n to 1, but the array indices range from n-1 to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats pretty simple: in Java all indexes are being stored from 0, not from 1.

So, `arr.length` actually returns lastArrayIndex + 1, and you can't access `arr[arr.length]`, because there is no element with such index.

And as the last index of array if `arr.length-1`, we start from it.

Your code is actually equal to this one (may be you will find it more straightforward):

```
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
        }
```

Sorry for posting it a seperate answer - not enough reputation for writing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the last index of an array is arr.length-1. Therefore, if you want to print the value starting from the last index it should be i-1. (Your i has been set to arr.length). If you don't want to have the arr[i-1]. You can do the following instead:

```
   //change i from arr.length to i = arr.length-1
   //change i>0 to i>=0
   //change arr[i-1] to arr[i]
    for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0;i--){


        System.out.print(arr[i ]+" ");


    }
```